# Making joins in R so that observations are only recorded once

Tags: r

I am joining two data frames in R and I only want a value from one of them to show up once. This scenario is similar to the code below. Suppose I have these customers given by the id in the code below. In the data frame, t, I have the customers id and the items they bought. In the data frame, t2, I have the total amount they spent. When I go to use a join, the total amount spent column gets used twice and throws off the numbers that I really want. Does anyone know how to fix this issue that can be used for large data frames?

```
t <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,3),product=c("a","b","b","c"))
t2 <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3),total_spent=c(12,23,24))
```

Comment: I am struggling to work out what you mean. What kind of join are you using? What is the output you are getting and what is your desired output?

Comment: Have you tried `left_join()`

Comment: This is my first post ever. 

@Tom Hoel I'm having trouble sharing the image of the output, but, yes, I have tried all joins and keep getting the same error.  @SamR I have tried all joins. The output I am getting is including the total_spent twice. I only want to see the total spent by each customer once, and I'd like to see the products that they bought as well. What I would like is something like 
```
data.frame(customer=c(1,1,2,3),product=c("a","b","b","c"),total_spent=c(12,NA,23,24))
```

Answer (score 0):

So, this output is not what you wanted?

```r
library(tidyverse)

t <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,3),product=c("a","b","b","c"))
t2 <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3),total_spent=c(12,23,24))

left_join(t, t2) %>%  
  as_tibble()

#> Joining, by = "id"
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>      id product total_spent
#>   <dbl> <chr>         <dbl>
#> 1     1 a                12
#> 2     1 b                12
#> 3     2 b                23
#> 4     3 c                24
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: That is correct. That is not what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on answer from @tom-hoel. You can use left join and then adjust `total_spent` to NA if id is not unique.

```
library(dplyr)
t <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,3),product=c("a","b","b","c"))
t2 <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3),total_spent=c(12,23,24))

t %>%
  left_join(t2, by = "id") %>%
  mutate(total_spent = ifelse(duplicated(id), NA, total_spent))
```

output

```
  id product total_spent
1  1       a          12
2  1       b          NA
3  2       b          23
4  3       c          24
```

see `?duplicated` and `?ifelse`

Or you can split total_spent by number of product within id.

```
t %>%
  left_join(t2, by = "id") %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(total_spent = total_spent / n())
```

Output

```
     id product total_spent
  <dbl> <fct>         <dbl>
1     1 a                 6
2     1 b                 6
3     2 b                23
4     3 c                24
```

Comment: This is closer to what I'm looking for. Thank you both for your contribution. I would like the problem to be solved in the join if it could. Manually removing the entries always seems like a sketchy way to do it, especially when working with big data. 
Again, thank you to you both, but I'd like to keep the discussion open to see if anyone else has anything else to add/build upon the current solutions.

Comment: @user19446714 The issue is that its not possible without reducing the information in first table `t`. You have two entries for one key and therefore you have to either reduce the table so all ids are unique or adjust `total_spent` after the join. I will expand my answer to show how to split total spent eqully by products.

Comment: This was my initial idea, but after considering it I decided it'd be best not to alter the total values as that might be misleading should anyone be interested in looking up these values. Thank you for all your help! 
I have had a positive first post experience.